# Convert date to specific format using Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am needing to convert records where the TEXT values look like this using Postgresql:

```
26-AUG-2015 
to:  
2015-08-26
```

I'm not sure what version of Postgresql exists on the vendor server but I tried to do a select statement using:

```
SELECT to_char(sle.log_field1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM student_log_entires sle;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function to_char(text, unknown) does not exist LINE 25: AND to_char(sle.log_field1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >=... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I did also try:

```
SELECT to_date(sle.log_field1, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM student_log_entries sle
```

But I got this error:

```
Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid value "[E] " for "YYYY" DETAIL: Value must be an integer. Query: SELECT to_date(sle.log_field1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM student_log_entries sle
```

Any suggestions/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This assumes that `lc_time` is set to English:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('26-AUG-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  to_char
------------
 2015-08-26
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the value to a date and then back to a string:

```
select to_char(to_date('26-AUG-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Under many circumstances, processing the value as a date is probably sufficient.

Your approach doesn't work because the value is apparently already stored as a string, so converting it back to a string with a date format doesn't make sense.

EDIT:

You may be able to get by using a simple regular expression:

```
select (case when col ~ '^[0-9]{2}[-][A-Z]{3}[-][0-9]{4}$' 
             then to_char(to_date('26-AUG-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        end)
```

Of course, if the formatting errors are more subtle, then a more complex regular expression would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However I got this error:

Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid value "[E" for "DD" DETAIL: Value must be an integer. Query: SELECT to_char(to_date(sle.log_field1, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM student_log_entries sle

Comment: So just using the to_date function should suffice as you stated?  Sorry I just want to make sure I'm clear on what you're saying.  Thanks.

Comment: It seens that there are entries that do *not* adhere to the format `DD-MON-YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT to_char(sle.log_field1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM student_log_entires sale;
```